# Can I write an iPython Notebook in a native python format?

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I want to write an iPython notebook, a set of answers to questions in a textbook, because I like the format.

But I don't want to leave my text editor, I want what I end up writing to be executable as the answers have definite values so I should be able to run each "answer" as a unit test.

Does a literate python environment like this exist?

Currently I have this setup, which is raw python, but I can't embed TeX or easily generate a well formatted document, which is something ipynb is really good at.

```
test_question_1():
"""Question: What is the area of a triangle with a base of 3cm and a height of 5cm?

Answer: The general equation for area of a triangle is 0.5*base*height.
"""
   base = 3
   height = 5
   target_answer = 7.5
   assert library.area(base=base, height=height) == answer
```

Comment: Not clear what you're looking for, maybe [doctest](https://docs.python.org/2/library/doctest.html)?

Comment: also look at [reStructuredText](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/rst.html) for LaTeX style math in documentation.

Comment: If you're looking for something that's basically an iPython Notebook with the ability to embed TeX, take a look at http://beakernotebook.com/.